# How to Customize Bootstrap css

Tags: css, next.js, react-bootstrap

I'm using react bootstarap for my next js project, I'm using bootstrap navbar, below is my sample code

```
<Navbar expand="lg">
      <Container className={styles.top_menu_pad}>
        <Navbar.Brand><Link href="/" passHref><a></a></Link></Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <NavDropdown title="Excel Courses" id="basic-nav-dropdown" style={{ position: "static" }}>          
              <ul>
                <li Col sm={4}>ddddd</li>
                <li Col sm={4}>ddddd</li>
                <li Col sm={4}>ddddd</li>
              </ul>
            </NavDropdown>
            <Link href="/worldwide-excel-training" passHref><Nav.Link>Upcoming Batches</Nav.Link></Link>
            <Link href="/results" passHref><Nav.Link>Excel Exam Results</Nav.Link></Link>
            <Nav.Link></Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
```

My requirement is the dropdown menu should be in full width, but i don't have option to customize the width of the dropdown, so kindly

I tried .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{width:100%} in my custom css, but it's not work for me, and I don't have option to give in Inline style.

Any one help me regarding this.

Comment: Don't use Container if u want full width menu.

Comment: Hi I want to increase the width of dropdown menu, by inspecting if I give width 100% for .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu it will works, but I don't know where to change this, because I cant access this class.